# Trouble with renaming/labelling drives in Ubuntu

Tags: compiling

I just don't understand what's wrong here, what's wrong with the drive names.
[link]http://i57.tinypic.com/264g7qb.png

As you can see I've labelled them with e2label command. I am only concerned with labelling them because I'll be using g++ for compiling .cpp files from the terminal so the command will go like
g++ /media/drivename/helloworld.cpp

Right now, the drives as in the screenshot are named something like

ae5bdc4c-586f-42de-b43c-94f7deedcb02  b7aaa7c8-63fa-4556-b028-c2242fdc3d59
how do I change the drive names from these random numbers to something simpler?

EDIT: I tried going to the drives in /mnt/ folder but it shows nothing. The df command however tells me that the drives are mounted 
http://i62.tinypic.com/2v3ltes.png

UPDATE:
so the /mnt/ is empty but the drives are there in the /media/ folder. Anyway the naming convention is what's bugging me here's is what it shows when i view their properties
the label is what i named with label command but the name is still those random messed up numbers ugh. Seriously, help me
i59.tinypic.com/2s76wcz.png

Answer (score 0):

Look in /etc/fstab and see where the partitions are mounted. Edit fstab to alter where the partitions are mounted and the name they are mounted under. eg. I have /dev/sdb2 mounted under /archive ..

$df -h

/dev/sdb2       139G   56G   76G  43% /archive

$blkid

/dev/sdb2: LABEL="archive" UUID="d3cf3600-f3d8-4ab8-8537-349dbeab7f1b" TYPE="ext4"

$cat /etc/fstab

UUID=d3cf3600-f3d8-4ab8-8537-349dbeab7f1b /archive  ext4    defaults,noatime 0 1

"Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if disks are added and removed."

Comment: They are not in /etc/ either. This is frustrating

Comment: Okay, so the mnt folder is empty but the drives are there in /media/ folder still there is something wrong with their names

Comment: To anybody wondering its the name of drive/partition im trying to change and not the LABEL unless you can refer to the partitions with their labels

Comment: "Edit fstab to alter where the partitions are mounted and the name they are mounted under"

Comment: fstab can't read all the drive names. Here are the concents of fstab

Comment: If you can't edit a text file, maybe you shouldn't be in 'web development'. My condolences for the loss of your deceased dear friend ..

Comment: My apologies for not finding your pointless trolling funny or amusing. If you read the post and write back with the intention of understanding what I'm talking about, and not with the motives of bashing me, will you know that I do not understand the contents of the fstab file which has nothing to do with 'web development'(implying you know what that means). The two partitions are not mentioned there. At this point I have no idea what those commands stand for or, are for.

Comment: [Troubleshooting problems that arise when mounting devices](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountDevicesTroubleshooting)

"Free your mind Neo, I can only show you the door. It is you who must walk through it."